# Excel count across multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

This is a fun challenge for Excel (me).  I have a spreadsheet that has the following columns:

```
Customer   Date    lat.  long.
```

Now, there are 10,000 of these in the initial dataset.  What I would like is a formula that will enable me to:

1. Find all other records that are less than six months in the future.
2. Calculate the distance between this Customer and each of the other records from #1.
3. Count the number that are both within six months and within one mile.
4. Repeat for each and every customer in the dataset.

I'm aware that there are ways of calculating the distance but the main thing is to figure out how to do both the six months in the future AND distance without precalculating all of the distances in a 10K x 10K grid.

Now, if I was working in a language, I'd simply do a loop and check each item and let it run.  However, the challenge is to prototype this AND prove to a friend that it is possible in Excel.

To add additonal notes based on the comment:

The main issue for me is not the distance calculation but rather getting the count of each of the results and then going through the entire list.  So for instance:

```
FIRST     12/01/1990   20  30
SECOND    04/02/1991   40  50
THIRD     05/16/1991   10  20
FOURTH    07/22/1991   50  60
```

Now assume that all I want is:  a count of the next six months and any x y (last two digits) that when added would be less than 51 from the current added x y of the current line.

For a small number of entries, I could simply create another column for the first to calculate and the do a count. What I'm not sure of is how to set up so that it only takes the next six months and then only runs a countif over the x y calculation in a single cell.  Seems to me, I want an array result of the dates are close enough and then do a distance calc on each member in the array and then count all those that come up positive. But implementing it in Excel is a bit of a challenge.

Any suggestions or other pointers?

thanks, -d

Comment: It's certainly possible in Excel. Could you clarify how you want the input and output? Do you only want to return the number from step 3? Anyway, if you figure out the date and distance calculation, putting it together should be easy.

Comment: The main issue for me is not the distance calculation but rather getting the count of each of the results and then going through the entire list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `SUMPRODUCT`:

- count customers in the next 6 months:
  `=SUMPRODUCT(([date]-[@date]<=183)*([date]-[@date]>0))`
- count customers less then 20 units away using a very simple formula (like on a plain surface):
  `=SUMPRODUCT((SQRT(([@[lat.]]-[lat.])^2+([@[long.]]-[long.])^2)<20)*1)`
- combining both criteria in one formula:
  `=SUMPRODUCT(([date]-[@date]<=183)*([date]-[@date]>0)*(SQRT(([@[lat.]]-[lat.])^2+([@[long.]]-[long.])^2)<20))`

[image]